# Control link styling within styled button

Tags: html, css

I made a navigation bar using CSS button styling and want each button to be a link. But when a user visits a link, then the link styling changes (adds an underline and makes the link text blue), and I can't figure out how to style the visited link within the button.

My code:

```css
.navbutton {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 95px 80px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbutton1 {
  background-color: 4CAF50;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  height: 50px;
  width: 130px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.navbutton1:hover {
  background-color: #0000FF;
  color: white;
  height: 50px;
  width: 130px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.navbutton1:visited {
  background-color: #0000FF;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  height: 50px;
  width: 130px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<button class="navbutton navbutton1"><a href="http://www.test.test">Home</a></button>
```

Is there a way to control the visited link style for this button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are adding styles to `.navbutton1` add styles to `anchor` tag also.

use this css

```css
.navbutton1 a{
color:white;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

```css
    <!--NAV BUTTONS-->
    .navbutton {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 95px 80px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 18px;
 font-weight:bold;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
    }

    .navbutton1 {
    background-color: 4CAF50; 
    color: white; 
    text-decoration: none;
 border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
 height: 50px;
 width: 130px;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 400;
    }

    .navbutton1:hover {
    background-color: #0000FF;
    color: white;
 height: 50px;
 width: 130px;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 400;
    }
    .navbutton1 a{
     color:white;
     text-decoration:none;
     }

    .navbutton1:visited {
    background-color: #0000FF;
    text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
 height: 50px;
 width: 130px;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 400;
    }
```

```html
<button class="navbutton navbutton1"><a href="http://www.test.test">Home</a></button>
```

Comment: Oddly your answered worked for my other pages (that happen to be php pages), but does not work on the home page (which is an html page). Not sure why or if the html page type is a problem? The button code is exactly the same and both pages point to the same css file. But the link style doesn't work for just the home page. Any idea why that could be?

Comment: check class names once.. in your code there are two classes `navbutton ` and `navbutton 1`

Comment: That might be related, but it works for all pages except one page which is an html page.  Anyway, I got it to work for that page too by moving the a tag outside the button like this: <a href="#"><button class="navbutton navbutton1">Home</button></a>

Answer (score 0):

```css
<!--NAV BUTTONS-->
.navbutton {
background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
border: none;
color: white;
padding: 95px 80px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight:bold;
margin: 4px 2px;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
transition-duration: 0.4s;
cursor: pointer;
}

.navbutton1 {
background-color: 4CAF50; 
color: white; 
text-decoration: none;
border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
height: 50px;
width: 130px;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 400;
}

.navbutton1:hover {
background-color: #0000FF;
color: white;
height: 50px;
width: 130px;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 400;
}


.navbutton1:visited {
background-color: #0000FF;
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
height: 50px;
width: 130px;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 400;
}

.navbutton1 a{
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
}

.navbutton1:hover a{
color: red;
}

.navbutton1 a:visited{
color: black;
}
```

```html
<button class="navbutton navbutton1"><a href="#">Home</a>
</button>
```

Here you go

```
.navbutton1 a:visited{
 //Your CSS styles
 }
```

Comment: I can make the text white for visited but it remains underlined. Can't remove the underline. Does this mean I can't use button and have to redo it all as styled links instead of buttons?

Comment: See my answer below. Add `text-decoration: none;`

Answer (score 0):

The `<a>` tags has a underline and a default color...So you will need to override the color by using `color:inherit` which inherit the color pf parent and also `text-decoration:none` to remove the underline.

Also no need to write the same css for on `:hover`....write only which style you want to change...

Also don't use html block comment tags `<!-- -->` in css...use `/*...*/`

```
.navbutton1 a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```css
.navbutton1 {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  height: 50px;
  width: 130px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.navbutton1:hover {
  background-color: #0000FF;
}

.navbutton1 a,
.navbutton1 a:visited,
.navbutton1 a:hover {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="navbutton navbutton1">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
</button>
```

Comment: I can make the text white for visited but it remains underlined. Can't remove the underline. Maybe we can't remove visited decoration. Does this mean I can't use button and have to redo it all as styled links instead of buttons?

Comment: Have you checked the above snippet result....it did applying any underline on link visit...Or just override all the `:hover` and `:visited` rule...check updated answer...!